# org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, spring-mvc

Hi i tried to resolve but i am failing to resolve it

getting **exception** like this

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:

[com.omnypay.dao.bo.CloudSvrUsersProfile#284]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.omnypay.dao.bo.CloudSvrUsersProfile#284]
```

Caused by:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was 
already associated with the session:
```

my user class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CLOUD_SVR_USERS")
@NamedQuery(name="CloudSvrUser.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM CloudSvrUser c")
public class CloudSvrUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="USER_ID")
        private long userId;

    it has some column and the oneto one relation like

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private CloudSvrUsersProfile usersProfile;

    and getters&setters
```

and my profile class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CLOUD_SVR_USERS_PROFILE1")
@NamedQuery(name="CloudSvrUsersProfile.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM CloudSvrUsersProfile c")
public class CloudSvrUsersProfile implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID",nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))

    private Long usersProfileId;
      //columns and

@OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private CloudSvrUser user;


    @Transient
    private String emailId;
```

and service impl class is

```
@Transactional
    public void UpdateUserProfile(CloudSvrUsersProfile userProf) throws BusinessException
    {
        try{
        CloudSvrUser dbUser = getUser(userProf);

        //CloudSvrUsersProfile dbUserProfile = dbUser.getUsersProfile();
        //CloudSvrUsersProfile updatedProf=userProf.getUsersProfile();
    if(dbUser != null){

            //CloudSvrUsersProfile newUserInfoList  = new CloudSvrUsersProfile();
            //CloudSvrUsersProfile newUserInfoList  = CloudSvrUsersProfile();
            CloudSvrUsersProfile updatedProf = new CloudSvrUsersProfile();

            updatedProf.setFirstName(userProf.getFirstName());
            updatedProf.setLastName(userProf.getLastName());
            updatedProf.setAddress1(userProf.getAddress1());
            updatedProf.setAddress2(userProf.getAddress2());
            updatedProf.setAddress3(userProf.getAddress3());
            updatedProf.setZipCode(userProf.getZipCode());
            updatedProf.setState(userProf.getState());
            //
            updatedProf.setStatus(Long.parseLong("1"));
            updatedProf.setCreatedBy(Long.parseLong("1"));
            updatedProf.setCreatedDate(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));



            //updatedProf.setEmialId(userProf.getEmialId());
            dbUser.setEmailId(userProf.getEmailId() );
            dbUser.setUsersProfile(updatedProf);
            updatedProf.setUser(dbUser);

            updateuser(dbUser);  


    }
        }
    catch(DaoException daoException) {

        throw new BusinessException(daoException.getMessage());
    }   

    }
```

for the 1st request its entering data to db but for second when i am changing some value and try to hit db from my url its giving the above exception

Please help me

Comment: post code for your service etc

Comment: Please paste the code which is causing this problem?

Comment: try
 {//
  super.getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
   //super.getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(user);
  //super.getHibernateTemplate().update(user);
  //this.userDao.updateUser(dbUser);
  
  

 }
 catch(DataAccessException accessException){
  
  throw new DaoException("Internal DB error occured.");
  
 }

Comment: this is my dao impl class and i have 2 more classes user and profile class and i have one to one relationship with userprofile

Comment: @smita don't add code into comments.. instate edit your question and add code of DAO and service class

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

cascade=CascadeType.ALL

from your User class.

Comment: thak you i resoved this issue